# how to convert bytes to a string in gdb

Tags: gdb

i have a word written like 0x46697273 how i can read symbols in gdb console ?

Comment: Do you mean symbols as in "debugging symbols" or just ascii characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean a character array located at that address?

Try using `x/s 0x46697273` .

Comment: 0x46697273:  <Address 0x46697273 out of bounds>

Comment: @RusAlex: they you're going to have to clarify what "a word written like 0x46697273" means in English.

Answer (score 0):

Cast it to a char pointer, something like `(char *)var`.